# get navigator stack length (tickers number)

Tags: flutter, dart

in my case, I want to do some logic based on navigator stack length.
as you saw, when you want to debug `NavigatorState`, it shows a text like:

```
NavigatorState#daea6(tickers: tracking 3 tickers)
```

but I got confused that how to get `tickers` number from `NavigatorState`.
because it's a private field.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the toString() method, then use the split() or subString() method; get the number string before 'tickers'.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35507101)

Comment: I have tested, this way could solve this question, get the number the asker wanted. Well, I know, it isn't the best way. But Flutter seems not provide a official way up to now.   @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine